# Is it possible to update input type text using css3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, keyboard

I've sample keyboard layout mentioned below: 
On click of every number on the screen, i want to get it updated in text area. 
On click of backspace, i want to remove last number. 
On click of clear all, complete text ares need to get cleared. 
On click of navigation keys < > cursor should move fordward and backwards in text area. 
Is there any way to achieve this using only CSS3? [Without using Javascript?]
If not, can you please suggest best option to achieve same? [Note : I'm not using any javascript on the page, so adding anything like jQuery will add overheads on page load time]

```
<html><head>
    <style> .vKeyboardSplKeys {
    background-color:#DEDBE4 ;
    border:1px solid #666666;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:arial;  
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px 6px;
    margin : 2px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.vKeyboardSplKeysHover {
    background-color:#8cb82b;
}.vKeyboardSplKeys:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

.vKeyboardKeys {
    width:9px;
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
    border:1px solid #666666;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:arial;  
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px 8px;
    margin : 2px;
    cursor:pointer;
}.vKeyboardKeysHover {
    background-color:#CEE9FC;
}.vKeyboardKeys:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

.space {
    padding : 3px 40px;
}

#vKeyboard{
    border : 1px solid #DDDDDDD;
    background-color : #F4F4F4;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
} </style>
</head>
<body>
    <center><input type="text" id="answer" value="">
    <div id="vKeyboard" style="width: 100px;"><span class="vKeyboardSplKeys vKeyboardSplKeysHover" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">Backspace</span><br><span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">7</span><span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">8</span><span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">9</span><br><span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">4</span><span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">5</span><span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">6</span><br><span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">1</span><span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">2</span><span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">3</span><br><span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">0</span><span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">.</span><span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">-</span><br><span class="vKeyboardSplKeys" data="left" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">&larr;</span><span class="vKeyboardSplKeys" data="right" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">&rarr;</span><br><span class="vKeyboardSplKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">Clear All</span><br></div></center>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using simple javascript, in this example you did not need to include any js file:

Here in the below example I have created one simple javascript function getValue() who is going to do desired task for you, Also I have implemented this with number 7 only. You have to code this function according to your needs...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .vKeyboardSplKeys {
        background-color:#DEDBE4 ;
        border:1px solid #666666;
        display:inline-block;
        color:#000000;
        font-family:arial;

        font-weight:bold;
        padding:3px 6px;
        margin : 2px;
        cursor:pointer;
      }
      .vKeyboardSplKeysHover {
        background-color:#8cb82b;
      }
      .vKeyboardSplKeys:active {
        position:relative;
        top:1px;
      }

      .vKeyboardKeys {
        width:9px;
        background-color:#EEEEEE;
        border:1px solid #666666;
        display:inline-block;
        color:#000000;
        font-family:arial;

        font-weight:bold;
        padding:3px 8px;
        margin : 2px;
        cursor:pointer;
      }
      .vKeyboardKeysHover {
        background-color:#CEE9FC;
      }
      .vKeyboardKeys:active {
        position:relative;
        top:1px;
      }

      .space {
        padding : 3px 40px;
      }

      #vKeyboard{
        border : 1px solid #DDDDDDD;
        background-color : #F4F4F4;
        padding:5px;
        text-align:center;
      }

  </style>
  <script>
    function getValue(val)
    {

      document.getElementById('answer').value = val;
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <input type="text" id="answer" value="">

      <div id="vKeyboard" style="width: 100px;">
        <span class="vKeyboardSplKeys vKeyboardSplKeysHover" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">
          Backspace
        </span>
        <br>
        <span onclick="getValue(7);" class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">
          7
        </span>
        <span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">
          8
        </span>
        <span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">
          9
        </span>
        <br>
        <span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">
          4
        </span>
        <span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">
          5
        </span>
        <span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">
          6
        </span>
        <br>
        <span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">
          1
        </span>
        <span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">
          2
        </span>
        <span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">
          3
        </span>
        <br>
        <span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">
          0
        </span>
        <span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">
          .
        </span>
        <span class="vKeyboardKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">
          -
        </span>
        <br>
        <span class="vKeyboardSplKeys" data="left" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">
          &larr;
        </span>
        <span class="vKeyboardSplKeys" data="right" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">
          &rarr;
        </span>
        <br>
        <span class="vKeyboardSplKeys" style="border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;">
          Clear All
        </span>
        <br>
      </div>

  </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhav. This is very much useful.

Comment: why not put border styles in a css class?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot border means border properties?

Comment: @Anubhav yes I know I means border properties but they can be put inside a cass declaration instead of putting inside each element.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot absolutely I have just copied that from the Question and then answered, Forgot to optimise html/css/w3c validator and all.

Answer (score 1):

Anything’s possible with enough HTML and CSS; however, we’re talking something like 20 × n! elements, which is definitely heavier than the equivalent JavaScript.

If you’d like to pursue it anyways, though, it looks like

```
<div id="initial">
    <a href="#1">1</a>
    <a href="#2">2</a>
    …
</div>
<div id="1">
    <a href="#11">1</a>
    <a href="#12">2</a>
    …
</div>
```

And then you’d create CSS to place the display box (which would have to come *after* the keypad in the markup) above the keypad, and then create an equivalent number of CSS rules with `#1:target ~ #input::after` and `content` properties to display the content. You would also not be able to use an `<input>`.

Creating a cursor would make for as many times as much work as possible positions there are in the box (1 + maximum length). Probably throw another factorial in there, unless you can make the CSS cleverer – not a good effort trade-off though, you’re already generating this using a program by now.

In case I wasn’t clear before, using CSS for this is highly inappropriate. What you’re looking for is behaviour, not presentation, and therefore belongs in JavaScript, not CSS.

Maybe even an `<input type="tel">`, perhaps?

Comment: Thank You for giving good direction & providing clarity; let me try this.